Kubuntu 24.04 .. Custom Shortcuts no longer working?
Subsequent to recently upgrading to Kubuntu 24.04, I can no longer find "shortcuts==>custom shortcuts"  "custom shortcuts service" is there, and lists my old shortcuts, but they no longer work.   Under "custom shortcuts service" I can not find any way to edit my old listed shortcuts, nor how to add a new one.  Help!

Ok so upon further investigation, I found that I had booted into Wayland.   Choosing Enlightenment or plasma(wayland) breaks the custom shortcut.   Booting back into Plasma(X11) and shortcut keys work fine.
